# Get only the required data from rest api

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a wordpress [blog](https://blog.varanjith.com) installed for testing purpose. I have an angular app which consumes the wordpress rest api. The app calls [an api](https://blog.varanjith.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/) which gets the categories. The json response has data which i'm not going to use in my app. So I created a model with only the value which I needed like name,slug etc. But When I consoled the response, it is showing the entire data. how can I restrict it?

Code:

**model**

```
  export interface BlogCategoryModel {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    slug: string;
    parent: number;
  }
```

**service**

```
  getCategories(): Observable<BlogCategoryModel[]> {
    const url = 'https://blog.varanjith.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories';
    return this.http.get<BlogCategoryModel[]>(url);
  }
```

**component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.blogService.getCategories().subscribe((x: BlogCategoryModel[]) => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  }
```

**output**

[image]

Why I'm seeing count and description in the console? Whats happening there? I haven't included count and description in the BlogCategoryModel

Comment: It's an interface. Just because the params aren't in your interface doesn't mean object implementing that interface won't have the extra fields. The interface just means that it should be expected to have those fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double check how typescript and HTTP client actually works : )

If you supply type parameter to HTTP client, it's not going to do anything with the response, only assign a type definition to it. This type definition can be really anything.

It's your job to consume it and pick only these properties that you actually need.

So in your case, you need to *map* your *response* first using `map` pipe and then map over categories array and pick required properties.

```js
getCategories(): Observable<BlogCategoryModel[]> {
    const url = 'https://blog.varanjith.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories';
    return this.http
        .get<BlogCategoryModel[]>(url)
        .pipe(
            map(categories =>
                categories.map(({ id, name, slug, parent }) => ({ id, name, slug, parent }))
            )
        );
}
```

This is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-caq5my) demonstrating it.

Comment: But I think it's a little confusing because as far as I remember http
        .get<BlogCategoryModel>.... would cast it automatically if I'm not wrong, but it apparently does not do it in this case (perhaps array?). The map method will work, indeed but it is not ideal since you have two sources of truth (ideally you will only have it defined in the interface).

Comment: Atleast I'm not alone. I had the same thought :P

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but you're wrong, Angular won't cast object automatically. This is the only true way as for now.

Comment: You are absolutely right.
In that case, I would probably just use some adapter pattern as a workaround. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `({ id, name, slug, parent }) => ({ id, name, slug, parent })` I suggest to use lodash `pick`. After all `pick` would make it more readable. `.pipe(map(categories => categories.map(category => _pick(category, ['id', 'name', 'parent']))))`

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Can be done in many ways, yep. It doesn't change the fact that response won't be casted to object automatically : ) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript itself doesn't say to api what it should and should not return. To use only those fields from your model you should handle the response in `map` operator:

```
getCategories(): Observable<BlogCategoryModel[]> {
    const url = 'https://blog.varanjith.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories';
    return this.http.get<BlogCategoryModel[]>(url).pipe(
       map((result: any[]) => {
           return result.map((category: any) => {
               return {
                   id: caregory.id,
                   name: category.name,
                   slug: category.slag,
                   parent: category.parent
               }
           })
       })
    );
  }
```